# Adding letters to my input box?

Tags: python

I am getting this error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'g'" when i input either a letter or decimal into my input box. The input box only takes whole numbers and I would like to know if it is possible to give a message saying that "You must enter a number" or something like that when they try and enter a letter. Heres some more of my code :

```
def checkAnswer():
    mainAnswer = entry1.get() 

    if len(mainAnswer) == 0:
        messagebox.showwarning(message='-You must enter some numbers first!')
        return
    if int(mainAnswer) != answer:
        messagebox.showwarning(message='Sorry...the correct answer is: ' + str(answer))
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo(message='Correct!')
```

Comment: This is python, right?

Answer (score 3):

The exception you get is when you try to do `int(mainAnswer)` when `mainAnswer` is not a number. One way to solve it is to do this:

```
try:
    int(mainAnswer)
except ValueError:
    messagebox.showwarning(message="You must enter a number")
    return

# the rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
   int_answer = int(mainAnswer)
except ValueError:
   int_answer = None
if int_answer is None:
   ...  # Show the error.
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I was thinking about it wrong. This will never work because the user isn't going to directly enter an int.

I would just check the type. Also, if you use elif you shouldn't need that empty return.  You also might need to reverse the type check, and the len check, but I don't think that matters for this answer.

```
def checkAnswer():
    mainAnswer = entry1.get() 

    if type(mainAnswer) != int:
        messagebox.showwarning(message='You must enter a number.')
    elif len(mainAnswer) == 0:
        messagebox.showwarning(message='-You must enter some numbers first!')    
    elif int(mainAnswer) != answer:
        messagebox.showwarning(message='Sorry...the correct answer is: ' + str(answer))
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo(message='Correct!')
```

Comment: If `mainAnswer` was originally an `int`, the OP would not get the exception that he mentioned.

Comment: Exactly the purpose of checking.

Comment: what I meant is that this check will *never* pass, because even though the user entered `123`, it will be a `string`, not an `int`.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking about it wrong. Thanks. I'll edit the answer.